# I'm using Kotlin, I want to custom the default tablayout into the tab that i has been do but i dont know which part that i have to change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

This is code of activity that has viewpager on it (ArtikelHome.kt):

```
package com.example.senangumrah

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.senangumrah.artikel.ArtikelViewPagerAdapter
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_artikel_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_artikel_home.navigation_button
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_artikel_home.tabLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_persediaan_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_artikel.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_menu.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_persediaan.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_persediaan.navigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_side_menu.*

class ArtikelHome : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.cover_home_artikel)
    onSetNavigationDrawerEvents()

    val adapter = ArtikelViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    viewPagerArtikel.adapter = adapter

    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPagerArtikel) { tab, position ->
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                tab.text = "Semua"
            }
            1 -> {
                tab.text = "Kat 1"
            }
            2 -> {
                tab.text = "Kat 2"
            }
            3 -> {
                tab.text = "Kat 3"
            }
            4 -> {
                tab.text = "Kat 4"
            }
            5 -> {
                tab.text = "Kat 5"
            }
        }
    }.attach()

    val ButtonBack: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.back)
    ButtonBack.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeMenu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    }
}
```

This the code for activity_artikel_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ArtikelHome">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/artikel_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.043"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttonback" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menubutton" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
    android:text="Artikel"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#1A1B23"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.182" />


<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="scrollabletab"
    app:tabMinWidth="105dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.125"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tabtext"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabtext"/>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerArtikel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This the code of viewpageradapter for artikelhome (ArtikelViewPagerAdapter):

```
package com.example.senangumrah.artikel

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter

class ArtikelViewPagerAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle):         FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle ) {
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 6
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (position) {
        0->{
            KategoriSemuaFragment()
        }
        1->{
            Kategori1Fragment()
        }
        2->{
            Kategori2Fragment()
        }
        3->{
            Kategori3Fragment()
        }
        4->{
            Kategori4Fragment()
        }
        5->{
            Kategori5Fragment()
        }
        else->{
            Fragment()
        }

    }
}
}
```

I have try using cardview but i cannot make the colour of tab change when select that tab. then i decide to use the default tablayout. The custom tablayout tht i want is when we select tha tab, the colour of the tab and the colour of text inside the tab change to another colour.

[The design that i want to create is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2q5I.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by following steps:

1. Create a custom layout for your tab item.
2. Add a function on your ArtikelViewPagerAdapter class.

   fun getTabView(position: Int): View {
   val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null)
   val tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
   tv.setText(tabTitles.get(position))
   val img: ImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imgView) as ImageView
   img.setImageResource(imageResId.get(position))
   return v
   }
3. Call this function from your TabLayoutMediator this way.

   tab.customView = mAdapter.getTabView(position)

Where mAdapter is your ArtikelViewPagerAdapter.